# Sprockets can't find bootstrap v3.3.5 while it finds v3.3.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sprockets

I am developing a Rails app (v4.2.1) which has a bootstrap installed on the `vendor/assets/components/bootstrap`.

Things went well until I upgraded the bootstrap from v3.3.4 to v3.3.5.

Now I see an error page that says `couldn't find file 'bootstrap' with type 'text/css'` .

Here is my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require fontawesome
 *= require_self
 */
```

If I downgrade the bootstrap to v3.3.4, this error disappears. Any suggestion?

[UPDATE]

I installed the boostrap with `bower install` command. The following is my `.bowerrc`:

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/components"
}
```

I have a directory tree like this:

```
vendor
  + assets
    + components
      + bootstrap
        + dist
        + fonts
        + grunt
        + js
        + less
        + .bower.json
        + ...
```

The version of sprockets is 3.2.0. I use also sprockets-rails 2.3.2 and sprockets-es6 0.6.2.

Comment: Additional infomation: The version of sprockets is 3.2.0. I use also sprockets-rails 2.3.2 and sprockets-es6 0.6.2.

Comment: Are you using the [`bootstrap-sass`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) gem?

Comment: @JeremyRodi No. I want to manage JavaScript packages with Bower. The point of my question is that what changed between v3.3.4 and v3.3.5 about bootstrap.

Comment: The reason I asked was so that I could check out the gem, and save some time.  Where do you install bootstrap then?

Comment: As I wrote, I installed bootstrap on the `vendor/assets/components` directory using Bower. I have specified this directory on `.bowerrc` and have an entry for `bootstrap` on `bower.json`.

Comment: Is there a `bootstrap.css{,.sass,.scss,.less}` file in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` directory?  Because if not, then that's your problem.

Comment: @JeremyRodi No. That is not the cause of my problem. See my answer. Thanks a lot, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of my question.

The bootstrap team changed the *main* section of `bower.json` as of `v3.3.5`. Before, it had these items:

```
"less/bootstrap.less",
"dist/css/bootstrap.css",
"dist/js/bootstrap.js",
"dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
"dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
"dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
"dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff",
"dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"
```

Now it has only two items:

```
"less/bootstrap.less",
"dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

We can follow the relevant discussions on https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16663. Put simply, they applied this change in accordance with the new bower specs https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec/pull/43. Currently, Sprockets can find only files listed in the *main* section of `bower.json`. That is my problem.

So, for a workaround I changed my `application.css` like this:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap
 *= require fontawesome
 *= require_self
 */
```

A fundamental solution would be a pull request to the https://github.com/rails/sprockets.

Comment: Did you have to do anything special to get your fonts to work? I can't get rails to include them in the pipline and so the paths are all messed up. Thanks!